# Handling meta data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, metadata

I am trying to read meta data from an html page using JavaScript. I created an array of all the meta tags and I am trying to read the property field, but I cant seem to get it to work. Here is the console:

```
>meta[6]
  <meta property=​"og:​image" content=​"http:​/​/​www. example.com/img/1.png">​
>meta[6].property
  undefined
>meta[6].content
  "http:​/​/​www. example.com/img/1.png"
```

How am I able to access the content but not the property field and how can I get the property?

Comment: Maybe more context can help. Is this an XML document? How are you getting the array?

Comment: expand your code, how did you get the meta tag, did you try to get it using getElementByTagName()? you know only the default properties work easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want the `getAttribute` function:

```
>meta[6].getAttribute('property');
   "og:image"
```

Comment: Achieves desired result but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: RobG's answer gives you the correct explanation. Attributes that are defined by the spec within the element are copied to properties on the DOM element. So you can access those with `meta.content` access. In your case `property` is not a standard. This is why jQuery now has both a $.attr() and a $.prop . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question:

> "How am I able to access the content
>   but not the property field"

*content* is a standard attribute of the [HTML meta element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META), so browsers will create an equivalent DOM property for the related DOM meta element.

*property* is not a standard attribute for the [HTML meta element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-META), so some browsers will not create a similar property (e.g. Firefox), while other browsers (e.g. IE) will. Therefore *[getAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9)* should be used for any non-standard attribute value, but direct DOM property access should be used for the values of standard attributes.

As a general rule, you should not use non-standard attributes on HTML elements, then you can always access values using DOM properties (which is the most appropriate method for HTML DOM elements).

Note that the [HTML5 meta element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#meta) is the same as the HTML 4.01 element linked to above, however the HTML 4 spec is probably the better one to use on the general web for the time being. HTML5-specific code should really only be used when targetting the HTML5 features of a particular browser.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete working example..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Cross-Window HTML</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Share Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Share Page Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Path to Share Image" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://127.0.0.1/newWindowWrite.html" />
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetMetaValue(meta_name) {

    var my_arr = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    for (var counter = 0; counter < my_arr.length; counter++) {
        console.log(my_arr[counter].getAttribute('property'));

        if (my_arr[counter].getAttribute('property') == meta_name) {
            return my_arr[counter].content;
        }
    }
    return "N/A";

}


function newHTML() {
    HTMLstring = '<html>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<head>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<title>Google +1</title>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<meta property="og:title" content="' + GetMetaValue('og:title') + '"/>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<meta property="og:description" content="' +  GetMetaValue('og:description') + '"/>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<meta property="og:image" content="' + GetMetaValue('og:image') + '"/>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<link rel="canonical" href="' + location.href + '"/>\n';
    HTMLstring += '</head>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<body>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<div id="shareContent">\n';
    HTMLstring += '</div>\n';
    HTMLstring += '</body>\n';
    HTMLstring += '</html>';
    console.log(HTMLstring);
    newwindow = window.open();
    newdocument = newwindow.document;
    newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
    newdocument.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="newHTML();">Spawn Sharing Window</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It fixes the problem, but it's way too long and doesn't explain the root cause. Especially considering the existing answers already mentioned what your code is doing

Comment: Hey no worries I just thought it would help to show a fully working piece of code that someone can work with and see how its working through the console. None the less, I needed to take out the Google +1 integration because it didn't work.  This is pretty straight forward now.. sorry to confuse.